# Is Java Enterprise Edition for web applications completely opensource?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is Java Enterprise Edition for web applications completely open source like PHP? Why is it called enterprise edition then?

Comment: Though I dont mind but I could not understand the reason for downvote for asking a question..that wasnt that silly or easy to be guessed by a newbie :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why does "enterprise" have to cost money or be closed-source?  It's called "Enterprise" because its the SDK and API for building enterprise applications that conform to the JavaEE spec.  The SDK and API are open-source, although the server implementations aren't always (some are, some aren't).

Comment: @Raj: That depends which JavaEE server you pick. Some are open-source and can be used for free (JBoss, Glassfish, for example), some can cost a fortune (Websphere, Weblogic). You pick the one that suits your needs. They're all JavaEE servers.

Comment: No, Java EE is an abstract API. The concrete implementations are Glassfish, JBoss AS, Geronimo, WebLogic, WebSphere, Resin, Tomcat, Jetty, etc..etc.. You're free to pick any one whichever you want based on your needs. Most of them are open source, some are not. Just consult its homepage for the details. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598798/what-is-glassfish

Comment: @Ray: Happy to help. Now ditch that PHP awfulness and come do some Java instead :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a different set up tools that is used to build web applications. They have a really good manual on Sun's website.

Intro:
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/firstcup/doc/

and here is the tutorial
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/

I read through those to get a good understanding.

Comment: I didnot downvote, but you should rather paste the link to licence and usage policy.

Comment: @Nishant: this does totally not answer the question.